# Unable to define resources for test target

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am trying to define resources for my testTarget in a way as it is described in [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/target/3583315-testtarget):

```
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "MyApp",
        dependencies: []),
    .testTarget(
        name: "MyAppTests",
        dependencies: ["MyApp"],
        resources: [.process("PerformancePath.json")]
    )
]
```

However, XCode gives me an error:

```
'testTarget(name:dependencies:path:exclude:sources:resources:cSettings:cxxSettings:swiftSettings:linkerSettings:)' is unavailable
```

And, after a while, all devices disappear from a list saying:

```
No devices because active scheme has no targets
```

Am I doing something wrong or it is a bug?

- Swift version: 5.3.3
- XCode version: 12.4 (12D4e)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to swift-tools-version. I had to [specify explicitly](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html) that I want to use version 5.3.